# C# why does using BeginInvoke delegate update datagridview with only the last of multiple entries

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm having an issue while updating a datagridview of on WinForm.  I set the DataSource of the datagridview to a bindinglist like so:

```
List<Data> rows = new List<Data>();

BindingList<Data> list = new BindingList<Data>(rows);

this.dataBindingSource.DataSource = list;
this.dataGridView3.DataSource = this.dataBindingSource;
```

In a different method within the class I am adding to the datagridview by adding to bindinglist like so:

```
Data theData = new Data();

....
//Data is an object with various getters and setters like
theData.price = ...
theData.qty = ...
....

this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { list.Add(Data); });
```

This works fine when I make single calls to the method that is updating the binding list.
But I have a situation where I am calling the method multiple times back to back from a different method like so:

```
updateRowMethod(....);
updateRowMethod(....);
```

The two calls are providing different data for the update.  But now the datagridview inserts 2 new rows but both rows contain the same data and in both rows it displays only the data passed in the second method call.

The method where rows are being added to the datagridview first updates a database with the data before adding it to the datagridview and on startup the datagridview is populated with data from the database.  Subsequently if I relaunch the application, the datagridview is populated with the correct data.  So the problem only occurs when viewing the new rows which are added while the application is currently running and being updated, the problem doesn't occur on restart and data is pulled from the DB.

I have put in breakpoints and see that the BeginInvoke line which adds the data is correctly being called twice for the 2 method calls and both times the correct data is coming into that line, and it is adding 2 new rows but it is only displaying data from the second function call.

I would greatly appreciate any insight you all may have.

Thanks

Comment: Is that inside `foreach` loop?

Comment: No its not inside a foreach

Comment: Fine, I don't want to take a guess. Post the relevant code(original) please. How you call `BeginInvoke` twice etc. So that it will be easy to answer. Issue is likely with  closing the same variable which changes its value.

Comment: Thanks.  No I wasn't making you guess. The method that has the begininvoke is called by a button click so actually those 2 method calls in my samples are all that is in the button clicked method, I've pretty much posted the meat of it, all else are just calling of some more setters for the Data object in the method that uses BeginInvoke.

Comment: Does it work if you add the data to `rows` instead of `list`?

Comment: @ Andrew Morton No if I add data to "rows" it won't even show any additions at all to the datagridview

Comment: From the "Thread Safety" sections of the docs for [BindingList(Of T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." Can you make `list` static? Or make a method which uses `lock` around the `list.Add(data)`? P.S. I don't get a notification if you put a space between the "@" and my name.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I gave putting a lock around the list.Add(data) and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Closures closures... Try the following:

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { 
     var thisData1 = Data; //this is important because it changes the context of the closure of the delegate.
     list.Add(thisData1); 
});
```

Comment: Yes exactly it still adds two rows but with data from only the second method call.

Comment: @Mzn `var thisData1 = Data;` should be outside of the `BeginInvoke` then it should work. Your code captures the closure as local variable again, it should be local before the closure happens. Or simply don't use `BeginInvoke`, just call `Invoke` everything should be fine then

Comment: Sorry, am still not sure whether this will work. `Data` is likely to be a class(reference type), when added to `list` twice also its values will not be copied. It will have same value only (unless OP created `new Data`)